# Iterate and compare 2 array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I'm trying to iterate information from 2 arrays through a table. Both tables have an identical "building" row, and for one cell of the table, I want to compare the contents of those rows. My code is below:

```
        <?php 
        $sql = "SELECT b.building, a.building FROM cms_TABLE_B b, cms_TABLE_A a WHERE a.building = b.building";
        $result = $database->query($sql);
        $availabilities[] = $database->fetch_array($result);
        ?>

        <?php foreach ($TABLE_ARecords as $record): ?>

        <div class="table-row">
            <div class="property"><span><?php echo htmlencode($record['address']) ?></span></div>
            <div class="availabilities"><span><?php if(in_array($record['building'], $availabilities)) { echo "success"; } else { echo "fail"; } ?></span></div>
        </div>

        <?php endforeach ?>
```

I'm trying to take the contents of "building" from TABLE_A and check if it matches the contents of "building" from TABLE_B. Ultimately, if the content matches I'd like to count the number of matches they have and display it in the table cell. I don't think I'm going about this the right way, as the $availabilities array doesn't even have the right information -- but using while causes the table to repeat itself. I don't want to display any information from TABLE_B, I just want to reference TABLE_A against it and display a count.

Comment: well, if you already have the buildings that you need in the array, you can use the count functions in php to see how many are there (count($array)). If you don't need the whole information about buildings, but only the number of matches, you should count them in the query, and return only that number SELECT count(*) FROM cms_TABLE_B b, cms_TABLE_A a WHERE a.building = b.building

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be a bit misleading. You are storing the results of the query in `$availabilities[]` yet you are looping through `$TABLE_ARecords`

As long as your query is correct, you can obtain the count using `count($availabilities)`

Speaking of your query, your table is requesting for the `'address'` of the building. I believe the query you are looking for is going to be something like

```
$sql = "SELECT a.building, a.address FROM cms_TABLE_A a 
        LEFT JOIN cms_TABLE_B b ON a.building = b.building";
```

Answer (score 1):

IT looks like you are trying to print more then just "number of matches".

Where are you getting $record['address']?  No where in your query are you getting address info.

Taking a guess here.  I would do:

```
 $query = "SELECT a.building,a.address,a.otherInfo FROM cms_TABLE_B b, cms_TABLE_A a WHERE a.building = b.building";
 $result = $database->prepare($query);
 $result->execute();
 while($row = $result->fetch())
 {
      echo "<tr><td>" . $row['building'] . "</td><td>" . $row['address'] . "</td><td>" . $row['otherInfo'] . "</td></tr>";
     //or whatever table format/div format you want to use.
 }
```

Comment: Just wondering, but why are you using a prepared statement that isn't preparing anything? Are there any advantages to this?